Error: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__func__'
First time using LangChain, I'm following a guide and I'm getting this error, does anyone know what might be wrong? I'm using Pinecone along with this, I'm not sure if that makes a difference.
For my Pinecone API environment I'm using "us-east-1" - I'm unsure if this is the right format?
I'd be very grateful for any input!
Many thanks in advance :)
So this is my code:
from langchain_community.vectorstores import DocArrayInMemorySearch

vectorstore1 = DocArrayInMemorySearch.from_texts(
    [
        "Mary's sister is Susana",
        "John and Tommy are brothers",
        "Patricia likes white cars",
        "Pedro's mother is a teacher",
        "Lucia drives an Audi",
        "Mary has two siblings",
    ],
    embedding=embeddings,
)

And I'm getting this error:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[58], line 3
      1 from langchain_community.vectorstores import DocArrayInMemorySearch
----> 3 vectorstore1 = DocArrayInMemorySearch.from_texts(
      4     [
      5         "Mary's sister is Susana",
      6         "John and Tommy are brothers",
      7         "Patricia likes white cars",
      8         "Pedro's mother is a teacher",
      9         "Lucia drives an Audi",
     10         "Mary has two siblings",
     11     ],
     12     embedding=embeddings,
     13 )

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\langchain_community\vectorstores\docarray\in_memory.py:68, in DocArrayInMemorySearch.from_texts(cls, texts, embedding, metadatas, **kwargs)
     46 u/classmethod
     47 def from_texts(
     48     cls,
   (...)
     52     **kwargs: Any,
     53 ) -> DocArrayInMemorySearch:
     54     """Create an DocArrayInMemorySearch store and insert data.
     55 
...

---> 46         return Generic.__class_getitem__.__func__(cls, item)  # type: ignore
     47         # this do nothing that checking that item is valid type var or str
     48     if not issubclass(item, BaseDoc):

AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__func__'

Unsure what to try!

That looks like an outdated langchain-community version. Try updating.

And if updating doesn't fix it, report a bug to their bug tracker. They are making some incorrect assumptions about the internals of python that they really shouldn't need to be making.
